# Appending already present element to DOM with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an element in my DOM with two children, a div block and a button. When I click the button, I want to add a new copy of the same div block to the parentNode. Is this possible? What I have in the button onclick call now is:

```
document.getElementById("myele").appendChild(document.getElementById("myele").children[0])
```

But this just moves that child in the children array under the button, and if I click again moves the button back under the div block (this because now children[0] is the button itself). I've also tried to assign the child Node to a variable and append that instead, but the result is the same.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without having to call a JS function that recreates the whole div block and then appends it?

**EDIT:** Having never used jQuery, I also tried to do this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
function addOne(){
    console.log('click')
    $('.valori:first-child').clone(true).appendTo($('.valori'))
}
</script>
```

and the onclick call became:

```
javascript: addOne()
```

The console logs 'click', but no changes in the page.

Comment: Put a space betwwen .valori and :first-child ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you right, `cloneNode` may be what you are looking for.

You could clone your element and then append the clone to your parent node.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!